# Issue with Recusive function

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

Been having an issue with a game I'm working on. The idea is based off of the card game WAR. I have a few functions to  flip the cards and check the values of the flipped cards which function fine. The problem occurs when the 'war' aspect comes in. For whatever reason, when the war is declared, the arrays in the console are populated with undefined values (up to about 400) and the recursive function continues to run until it hits a set number of times. All data is being displayed in the console. My question is, why is this happening? It is not intentional for anything to be populated or for the war function to run that many times. Is it an issue with how the arrays are being filled with data or is it a problem with the recusive function? I really don't know, but if anyone has an ideas, I'm all ears.

```js
const flipBtn = document.getElementById("flipBtn");
let player1Cards = [4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4];
let player2Cards = [4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3];
//tempArrays
let tempArr1 = [];
let tempArr2 = [];
flipBtn.addEventListener("click", flipCards);
//function to (in essence) flip the cards
function flipCards(){
    //if both deck have cards in them
    if(player1Cards.length !== 0 && player2Cards.length !== 0){
        //create temp array to hold player card
        let tmpPlayerCard = player1Cards.shift();
        tempArr1.unshift(tmpPlayerCard);
        console.log(tmpPlayerCard);
        //create temp array to hold comp card
        let tmpCompCard = player2Cards.shift();
        tempArr2.unshift(tmpCompCard);
        console.log(tmpCompCard);
        //run check cards
        checkCards(tmpPlayerCard, tmpCompCard);
    }
}
//function to check the value of cards, where x is playerCard and y is compCard
function checkCards(x, y){
    //if playerCard value is higher than compCard
    if(x.value > y.value){
        //push both cards into player1Cards
        player1Cards.push(x, y);
        console.log(player1Cards);
    }
    //if compCard value is higher than playerCard value
    else if(x.value < y.value){
        //push both cards into player2Cards
        player2Cards.push(x, y);
        console.log(player2Cards);
    }
    //when both values are even
    else{
        //push values into respective temporary arrays
        tempArr1.push(x);
        tempArr2.push(y);
        //run the war function
        war(0);
    }
}
// puts 4 additional cards into tempArr's, then checks the values, x is meant to set the amount of times a recurive function will run
function war(x){
    //if x ends up reaching 100, stop function
    if(x >= 100) return;
    // pushes 4 additional cards into tempArrays
    for(let i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
        // variables to hold card the first objects from respective player deck arrays
        let card1 = player1Cards.shift();
        let card2 = player2Cards.shift();
        //push cards into respective arrays
        tempArr1.push(card1);
        tempArr2.push(card2);
        console.log(tempArr1);
        console.log(tempArr2);
    }
    //if the player's 5th card value is higher than the comp's 5th card value
    if(tempArr1[4] > tempArr2[4]){
        console.log("Player 1 wins the war");
        //function calls to push tempArr's into player card array
        pushArray(tempArr1, player1Cards);
        pushArray(tempArr2, player1Cards);
        //empty tempArrays so they can be used again
        tempArr1, tempArr2 = [];
    }
    //if the comp's 5th card value is higher than the player's 5th card value
    else if(tempArr2[4] > tempArr1[4]){
        console.log("Player 2 wins the war!");
        //function calls to push tempArr's into comp card array
        pushArray(tempArr1, player2Cards);
        pushArray(tempArr2, player2Cards);
        //empty tempArrays so they can be used again
        tempArr1, tempArr2 = [];
    }
    //if both values are the same again
    else if(tempArr1[4] === tempArr2[4]){
        //run function recursively, update x
        war(x + 1);
    }
}
//function to push objects from an array into another array
function pushArray(fromArray, toArray){
    for(let i = 0, len = fromArray.length; i < len; i++){
        toArray.unshift(fromArray[i]);
    }
    return toArray;
}
```

```html
<button id="flipBtn">Flip Cards</button>
```

Output

```
[
  4,
  4,
  4,
  5,
  3,
  5,
  4,
  3,
  3,
  3,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,  // repeats ...
]
```

Comment: What is your question?  What is this doing differently than it should, and what should it be doing instead?

Comment: So it is not supposed to run over and over again until the end of time, or get populated with undefined data. It is only meant to hold, in this version, a small amount of data and said data is meant to be pushed from array to array when needed, like cards are to a players deck in war. But i did update my description to ask a hopefully better question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't normally write answers like this but it's hard to debug code when there is so much indirection. Quite frankly, the program you have written is mostly unsalvageable. Consider a more direct approach. If you have any questions, I'm happy to assist -

```js
let war = document.forms.war
let p1 = [5,3,8,3,8,9,4]
let p2 = [4,4,5,3,8,2,4]
let round = []
let message = "war"

function play() {
  if (message == "p1 wins") win(p1)
  else if (message == "p2 wins") win(p2)
  const a = p1.shift(), b = p2.shift()
  round.push([a,b])
  if (a == null) message = "gameover. p2 wins"
  else if (b == null) message = "gameover. p1 wins"
  else if (a > b) message = "p1 wins"
  else if (a < b) message = "p2 wins"
  render()
}

function win(p) {
  while (round.length) p.push(...round.pop())
  round = []
  message = "war"
}

function render() {
  war.p1.value = JSON.stringify(p1)
  war.p2.value = JSON.stringify(p2)
  war.round.value = JSON.stringify(round)
  war.message.value = message
}

war.flip.addEventListener("click", play)
render()
```

```html
<form id="war">
  <div>p1: <output name="p1"></output></div>
  <div>p2: <output name="p2"></output></div>
  <div>round: <output name="round"></output></div>
  <div>status: <output name="message"></output></div>
  <input name="flip" type="button" value="flip">
</form>
```

Comment: Yeah, my version kinda got away from me, it was test to see if I could even build something like War. But your version is very clean, robust and easy to read. Thanks for showing me a much easier way to do this haha. One question tho: "p.push(...round.pop())" I'm not sure what the purpose of the triple dots is in this line and haven't found a good explanation of what it does. If you could explain that, that would be awesome! Thanks again!

Comment: You're very welcome. The `...` [spread argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is used to unload the `round` array. `p.push(...[5,4])` is the same as `p.push(5,4)`. Without using `...` we would push an array to `p`, but the spread argument pushes each element of the array to `p` :D

Comment: Gotcha, good to know. Thank you again! I think this will help tremendously with getting this little experiment done

Comment: Gotcha, good to know. Thank you again! I think this will help tremendously with getting this little experiment done

Answer (score 0):

During the first run of your `war` function your temporary arrays look like this;

```
tempArr1 - [4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5]
tempArr2 - [4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5]
                        ^
                        Pay attention here.
```

You then do a couple of checks on the 5th entry in both of these arrays ( `tempArr1[4]` )

Your first check is to see if `tempArr1[4]` is larger than `tempArr2[4]`, it isn't.

You then proceed to check if `tempArr2[4]` is larger than `tempArr1[4]`, it isn't.

You then proceed to check if they are equal, which they are, both equate to the value of 3.

When both are equal, you run the `war` function again.

However, you never reset temporary arrays and only `push` data to the **end** of them, meaning that in subsequent runs of the `war` function `tempArr1[4]` and `tempArr2[4]` will **always** be their initial value of 3.

```
tempArr1 - [4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 1, 3, etc]
tempArr2 - [4, 4, 4, 5, 3, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 5, 1, 1, 3, etc]
                        ^
                        Pay attention here.
```

And as for where the *undefined* values are coming from, that is because after X amounts of recursion both `player1Cards` and `player2Cards` are empty so `.shift()` [returns undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift#return_value).

Comment: Ahhh okay, that makes a lot more sense. I'm new to recursive functions so I'm still getting used to them. But I think I can see the error in the logic there. Thank you for explaining that in such detail, maybe there's a way to revamp this a bit now